# Algebra of Subsets with disjoint sets whose unions are equal

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-measure

If $A$ is an algebra (of subsets of $\mathbb{R}$) and $E_1,E_2,...$ are elements of $A$. Show that there are dijoint sets $F_1,F_2,...$ elements of $A$ with $\cup E_n=\cup F_n$ from $n=1$ to infinity.

Okay so if $F_1,F_2,...$ are disjoint then the intersection of $F_n$ will be the null set which is contained in $A$ so the intersection of the $F_n$ are contained in $A$.

I understand from the property of algebras that countable unions are contained in $A$ too but I'm not sure how to show that these two things are equal.

Comment: Perhaps let $F_1,F_2,\dots$ be special in some way.  How about let $F_1=E_1$ and $F_2=E_2\setminus E_1$?  Does this make it so that $F_2$ is disjoint from $F_1$ and $F_2\cup F_1 = E_2\cup E_1$?  Is $F_2$ an element of $A$?  What might you let $F_3$ be?

Comment: Ahh I think I get you. I imagine F2 is still an element of A as they are defined as disjoint sets in A. I suppose continue the series along F3=E3/E2 and so F3UF2UF1=E3UE2UE1 and conclude that its the same upto infinity?

Comment: But $F_3 = E_3\setminus E_2$ might not necessarily be disjoint from $F_1$.  Close though,

Comment: So if I left F3=E3\E2\E1 that mean they would all be disjoint

Comment: Yes.  Worded a different way, $F_i = E_i\setminus \left(\bigcup_{j=1}^{i-1} E_j\right)$.  It remains to show *why* every $F_i$ is actually an element of the algebra however.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

If I like to meet and talk to everyone I possibly can at least once and I go to parties every day, at each party I have the following options:

- Talk to everyone at every party
- Talk to only those people at the party whom I haven't met before

Try to relate this to the problem at hand and reword in terms of mathematical symbols.  Be sure to explain *why* your sets $F$ are included in the algebra in question.

---

Since it has been figured out in the comments above, the sequence $E_1,E_2,\dots$ corresponds to speaking with everyone at every party.  The sequence $F_1,F_2,\dots$ corresponds to speaking with only those people at each party who hasn't been spoken to at previous parties.

With symbols, $F_i = E_i\setminus\left(\bigcup_{j=1}^{i-1} E_j\right)$

It can easily be checked that $F_i\cap F_j = \emptyset$ for all $i\neq j$ and that $\bigcup F_i = \bigcup E_i$.

What remains to be shown is why each $F_i$ is an element of the algebra

> Remember that algebras are closed under finite union and finite difference.  $\sigma$-algebras are additionally closed under countable union.  So, $\bigcup_{j=1}^{i-1} E_j$ is an element of the algebra and so $E_i\setminus \left(\bigcup_{j=1}^{i-1} E_j\right)$ is also as it is the difference between two elements of the algebra.